Speakers disappeared from settings after installing HDAjackretask
I have a Msi laptop (MSI GF63 (Intel® 8th Gen / GeForce® GTX 10 series)) and was trying to make the speakers sound better, and installed hdaJackretask.
Every time I try to use it, it makes my computer crash. And no changes were saved. Suddenly, my speakers disappeared from my sound settings and my laptop is mute.
I have the latest version of Ubuntu (24.04)

There is not such version of Ubuntu called latest. An actual version number is always required. Later could be different a week from now.

@DavidDE very helpful
